# Android in-app billing (IAB Version 3)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have tried the sample application of in-app billing for version 3 http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample? App is TrivialDrive. When i tried to test the app by following the steps in README. file. After uploading it to market as draft and tried to purchase a in-app using a test device i received a eror message that **User is not eligible for this purchase**.                                 Why iam receiving this message Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

The actual reason for this error:

If an unauthorized user try to purchase an item them this message should appear.

So if the App is not published, a non test user should get this error while try to purchase.

I realized that, Google play takes time to update the changes in app store. So you can not expect the changes immediately. Rather you should wait, in my case it took average 2/3 hours.

Still there may be some unknown error, which I could not figure.

#### My Cases:

First I was trying to purchase from my test device still got this error, But after waiting some time I didn't get this error. So I think the time was reason here.

Secondly I was trying from a non test device, which was an unauthorized device as the app was not published.

Comment: I have tested the uploaded app after many hrs only. I have followed the steps mentioned in Android developers site to test the in-app, also mentioned a test account using that only im trying to purchase the app

Comment: - Make sure that your device root user is listed as a test user.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by changing the "License Test Resonse" to "LICENSED" on the User Accounts and Rights Tab.

====================== edit =================================

OK Here are the exact instructions to find this setting:

In the Google Play Developer Console, using the "new design" there is on the left "All applications" "Reports" and "Settings."    Choose Settings.

There is a License Testing  box.  You must enter the gmail address of the account that is on the test device.  This cannot be the same as the email address of the developer account. (You cannot buy from yourself.)

Below License Testing, there is a "License Test Response" Dropdown.  Choose LICENSED.

I suppose that this is described in the docs someplace, but I missed it :)

Comment: I have changed the license settings but still im unable to buy the sample app from android market using testing device? is the changes made in console  takes more hours to reflect?

Comment: I have been letting things rest overnight. The 2-3 hours that others advise on here was not enough.    So far as I know, there are only a few reasons you might not be "Eligible"   1. The test account is not the primary account on the test device.  2. The test account is not listed under "Gmail accounts with testing access" or 3. The License Test Response is not set to Licensed.  or maybe 4. The license key for the app didn't get copied correctly into the source code for the app. (No spaces inside " ")  5. The test account does not have a credit card associated with it.